# Mongodb project results into single document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e81f1da5ea3cb7c248a8f"), 
    "type" : "TYPE_1", 
    "updateTime" : ISODate("2020-08-24T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e8206da5ea3cb7c248a90"), 
    "type" : "TYPE_1", 
    "updateTime" : ISODate("2020-09-24T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e821fda5ea3cb7c248a91"), 
    "type" : "TYPE_2", 
    "updateTime" : ISODate("2020-09-25T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
```

I want to know how many documents there are of each type and also obtain the date of the last global modification. For now I can get these results like this:

```js
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                      _id : "$type",
                      count: { $sum: 1 },
                      lastUpdate: { "$max": "$updateTime" }      
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $sort: { 
              lastUpdate : -1
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

With which I get the results this way:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : "TYPE_2", 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2020-09-25T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "TYPE_1", 
    "count" : 2.0, 
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2020-09-24T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
```

So I have both the sum of each document and the last modification (thanks to the sort).

But I would like to project and get the results like this, in a single result document:

```js
{ 
    "type1" : 2.0, 
    "type2" : 1.0, 
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2020-09-25T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
```

Comment: What if the update times are different for different types, should they all be counted in the same document or a separate document for each lastUpdate timestamp?

Comment: I am interested in getting the last timestamp of the entire collection, regardless of the type, in the same result document. In fact in the example all the timestamps are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@varman's answer is good, this is just in different way,

- `$group` you have already done by your self
- `$group` create types array to combine all documents
- `$replaceWith` to replace root with field types to convert `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      lastUpdate: { $max: "$updateTime" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      types: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      },
      lastUpdate: { $max: "$lastUpdate" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        { lastUpdate: "$lastUpdate" },
        { $arrayToObject: "$types" }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jgv2jk6sdi0)

Comment: working in playground. But when i run on muy server (4.2.8) updateTime is wrong ```{ 
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2020-09-24T11:10:43.219+0000"), 
    "TYPE_1" : 2.0, 
    "TYPE_2" : 1.0
}```

Comment: sorry for that, was a mistake, you can check now, i have updated,

Comment: i think working perfect with ```lastUpdate: { $max: "$lastUpdate" }```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following stages after your stage.

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          type: "$_id",
          count: "$count"
        }
      },
      lastUpdate: {
        $first: "$lastUpdate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$data",
            in: {
              k: "$$this.type",
              v: "$$this.count"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      lastUpdate: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.lastUpdate": "$lastUpdate"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  }
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-yPsNOzO6FC)

Comment: Working in mongo playground but when i run in my server (4.2.8) im getting two documents ```{ 
    "TYPE_2" : 1.0, 
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2020-09-25T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
{ 
    "TYPE_1" : 2.0, 
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2020-09-24T11:10:43.219+0000")
}
```

Comment: working! thank you! I'm going to see what is the best solution